# Incorrect type deduction after assertion?

Tags: typescript, types, assertion, type-deduction

In the following example I feel that the type deduction is wrong. Using the new `asserts` functions, we can assert the type for the scope which after the assertion is deduced correctly. But then if I try to pass the `args` object from the example to a function that expects `value` to be string, the `Foo` type is used just as if no assertion was made.

```
function assert(condition: any, msg?: string): asserts condition {
    if (!condition) throw new Error(msg);
}

type Foo = { value: string | [string, string] };
const Func = (args: { value: string }) => null;

const args: Foo = null;
args.value; // Deduced: string | [string, string]
assert(typeof args.value === "string");
args.value; // Deduced: string
Func(args); // Error: Type '[string, string]' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

In this next example the deduction works correctly though.

```
type A = { type: "A"; value: string };
type B = { type: "B"; value: [string, string]};

const args2: A | B = null;
args2.value; // Deduced: string | [string, string]
assert(args2.type === "A");
args2.value; // Deduced: string
Func(args2); // OK
```

I see what differences between these two examples are, but still since in the first example the `args.value` is asserted to be of `string` type, shouldn't the `args` object for the rest of the scope behave just as if `value` was of type `string` even when passed somewhere as a whole object?

Comment: Type guards have always impacted just the type of checked property not of the whole object for non-discriminated unions (the pattern for discriminated unions requires the discriminating property to be a literal type as well as a few other cases)

Comment: So it must be a discriminated union in order for the type deduction to work on object level?

Comment: Yes it has to be a discriminated union to get the narrowing of the type at the object level